# mkpasswd -m sha-512 produces incorrect login

Tags: 16.04, bash, login, password

I'm running into trouble trying to set passwords for my new users.

I found a tutorial indicating that `mkpasswd -m sha-512 "my password here"` would produce a salted and hashed password that can be used in combination with `useradd -m -p "hashed and salted passwd" -s /bin/bash username`, however when I tried this on a test user, I keep receiving `Incorrect Login`.

I am running Ubuntu 16.04 and using `mkpasswd` from the `whois` package.

What am I doing wrong here?

---

### Exact Steps

1) `apt update`

2) `apt install whois`

3) `mkpasswd -m sha-512 "my password here"`

produces: `$6$1FuuSdKgVke$bc8doOVGZhzomoeafvcQnpYhAxfR4aWdAuYvbxSHw6ZCFZ4NC5j9C762kmvs4Pc66bv4.LYTfrlknm5cWx65g.`

4) `useradd -m -p $6$1FuuSdKgVke$bc8doOVGZhzomoeafvcQnpYhAxfR4aWdAuYvbxSHw6ZCFZ4NC5j9C762kmvs4Pc66bv4.LYTfrlknm5cWx65g. -s /bin/bash testuser`

5) `login testuser`

Prompts for password:

6) type my password here

Says: `Login incorrect`

---

Would like to add that I tried the same thing with a password that has no spaces, and omitted the quotes from the `mkpasswd` command. Neither seemed to make a difference.

I also tried to make the user without the -p flag (meaning don't add a password) and manually copied the salted/hashed password into `/etc/shadow` which produces the same results as above, Login incorrect.

---

Even more interesting, if I use a subshell to put the value in, everything seems to work fine.

`useradd -m -p $(mkpasswd -m sha-512 "my password") -s /bin/bash test`

`login test`
type: `my password`

Logs in just fine!

Comment: Can you provide the link to that tutorial as I don't see any `-m` option for that command unless I am missing something?

Comment: @George  Do you have `whois` package installed ? Check with `apt-cache policy whois`. The option is there.

Comment: `whois:
  Installed: 5.2.11
  Candidate: 5.2.11
  Version table:
 *** 5.2.11 500
        500 http://ng.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status` I still don't get, excuse my inexperience

Comment: @Neurax can you provide the *exact* steps you did ? How did you combine the two commands ?  Both commands appear correct, so there must be something you did incorrectly

Comment: I added my steps.

Comment: @George not sure which command you're talking about, but, the -m flag in the `mkpasswd` command sets the method to use for the encryption, and in the `useradd` command, the -m flag specifies to create a home directory for the new user.

Comment: I tried to create the actual has which represents the password my actual user has and compared it with the entry in /etc/shadow and in all tries of which mkpasswd always created a different output for the same string it never matched my actual password. And can you link that tutorial please.

Comment: @Videonauth that's because each use of the `mkpasswd` utility will generate a different salt to use during encryption. If you specify which salt to use using the `-s "11223344"` option, you'll see it come out the same each time. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/187333/why-mkpasswd-m-sha-512-produce-different-result-every-time-it-is-called you could grab the salt from your `/etc/shadow` entry and try it with that flag and you should get the same hash.

Comment: I shouldn't have said tutorial. I meant the man pages for `useradd` and `mkpasswd`.

Comment: Ok just took the salt from the shadow file and took my password string, and the results still don't match. However the part where the salt is matches, but the rest don't. Try it `sudo grep "<main user>" /etc/shadow` and `mkpasswd -m sha-512 "<main-user-password>" -s <salt>`

Comment: Did you grab the proper salt? The $6 in the beginning isn't part of the salt. It's the 8 chars that follow the $6. I've done exactly what you said in your comment as a test and received the OPPOSITE results.

Comment: Yep i did  $6$<salt>$<hash> :)

Comment: So then why does the subshell work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I locked down the issue. Since the output of `mkpassword` will result in `$id$salt$hash`, when you copy and paste this into a `useradd` command, bash will try and do variable replacement on the `$`. As such, those need to be escaped using `\$id\$salt\$hash` so that bash will not do variable replacement before adding the string to `/etc/shadow`.

`mkpasswd -m sha-512 "my password"`
results in

`$6$5AfGzrQ9u$r6Q7Vt6h8f2rr4TuW4ZA22m6/eoQh9ciwUuMDtVBX31tR3Tb0o9EB1eBdZ2L9mvT.pX3dIEfxipMoQ0LtTR3V1`

which can be copied and pasted into `useradd` making sure to replace each `$` with `\$`.

`useradd -m -s /bin/bash -p \$6\$5AfGzrQ9u\$r6Q7Vt6h8f2rr4TuW4ZA22m6/eoQh9ciwUuMDtVBX31tR3Tb0o9EB1eBdZ2L9mvT.pX3dIEfxipMoQ0LtTR3V1`

Comment: My system was playing tricks on me, and you could always do `mkpasswd -m sha-512 "my password" | sed 's/\$/\\$/g' > out.txt` to save yourself the replacement of `$` with `\$` :-)

Answer (score 3):

## Why does this happen ?

The reason why it fails is because items with leading `$` are treated as variable and are unquoted when you pass it to `useradd`.

The `$6...`,`$1...`, and `$b...` portions from your hash are treated as variable. Of course, the fault is with the shell - shells perform variable expansion (unless they're single-quoted ) before anything runs. And because those 3 variables don't exist in your environment they disappear from the string you pass to `useradd`.

#### Practical example:

Let's see what *actual* command runs after the shell finished performing all necessary expansions and substitutions and passed that to `execve()` system call. Compare:

```
$ strace -e execve useradd -p $abra$cadabra newuser                                                                                                                    
execve("/usr/sbin/useradd", ["useradd", "-p", "newuser"], [/* 82 vars */]) = 0

$ strace -e trace=execve useradd -p '$abra$cadabra' newuser                                                                                                            
execve("/usr/sbin/useradd", ["useradd", "-p", "$abra$cadabra", "newuser"], [/* 82 vars */]) = 0
```

In the first example `$abra$cadabra` ( which is where your hash would go) disappears from the command that actually gets to run by the system. In contrast, the single quoted `$abra$cadabra` in the second example appears on the list of arguments that do get passed to `execve()`.

In other words, you generated correct hash, but shell passes completely different thing to `useradd` as argument, which ultimately is the command that system runs. In fact, let's just take your hash for instance and compare two cases of quoting and non-quoting:

```
$ strace -e execve echo $6$1FuuSdKgVke$bc8doOVGZhzomoeafvcQnpYhAxfR4aWdAuYvbxSHw6ZCFZ4NC5j9C762kmvs4Pc66bv4.LYTfrlknm5cWx65g                                                            
execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "FuuSdKgVke.LYTfrlknm5cWx65g"], [/* 82 vars */]) = 0
FuuSdKgVke.LYTfrlknm5cWx65g
+++ exited with 0 +++
```

Notice that what system actually sees after the shell is done processing the variables is `FuuSdKgVke.LYTfrlknm5cWx65g`. But it will see the correct hash if you quote it:

```
$ strace -e execve echo '$6$1FuuSdKgVke$bc8doOVGZhzomoeafvcQnpYhAxfR4aWdAuYvbxSHw6ZCFZ4NC5j9C762kmvs4Pc66bv4.LYTfrlknm5cWx65g'                                                          
execve("/bin/echo", ["echo", "$6$1FuuSdKgVke$bc8doOVGZhzomoeaf"...], [/* 82 vars */]) = 0
```

## What can be done ? What works ?

However, subshell works because there is no replacement occurring - there's no variables. And quoting also works for the same reason.

Here are a few methods:

1. Command substitution:

   ```
   $ sudo -p ">" useradd -m -s /bin/bash -p $(mkpasswd --hash=SHA-512 "123" ) newusr        
   >
   $ su newusr
   Password: 
   newusr@ubuntu1604:/home/admin$
   ```
2. Single-quoting(note that I've trimmed actual hash because it's too long and doesn't fit into formatting):

   ```
   $ sudo -p ">" mkpasswd --hash=SHA-512 "112"
   >
   GVhvDY$vhw89D2X0bd2REQWE
   $ sudo -p ">" useradd -m -s /bin/sh -p 'GVhvDY$vhw89D2X0bd2REQWE' newusr2
   > 
   $ su newusr2
   Password: 
   $ echo $USER
   newusr2
   ```
3. Take output from `mkpasswd`'s `stdout` stream and pass it via `xargs` with `-I` flag:

   ```
   $ mkpasswd -m sha-512 'password1' | sudo -p '>' xargs -I % useradd -p % newuser1
   ```
4. Append `\` to every `$` (which OP figured out themselves in [their answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/982857/295286)). Scriptable, too, as per [George's comment](https://askubuntu.com/questions/982804/mkpasswd-m-sha-512-produces-incorrect-login/982859#comment1580773_982857).

   ```
   $ useradd -m -s /bin/bash -p \$6\$5AfGzrQ9u\$r6Q7Vt6h8f2rr4TuW4ZA22m6/eoQh9ciwUuMDtVBX31tR3Tb0o9EB1eBdZ2L9mvT.pX3dIEfxipMoQ0LtTR3V1 newuser
   ```

Comment: Haha, we were both working on this solution simultaneously. I snuck an answer in 5 minutes ahead. Good find brother, you can have the answer credit! You should definitely edit your solution to include the easy fix of escaping the `$` with `\$` for thoroughness.

Comment: Looking through your solution, I can't really tell what you're doing with strace, and further, executing `sudo -p ">"` is confusing to anyone looking at this question. It doesn't have anything to do with the reason why the manual setting of the hash wasn't working. I'd remove that also.

Comment: @Neurax I'll add explanation on `strace` and `\$`. As for `sudo -p ">"`  it's just to hide my  actual username ( although granted - it's already all across the internet anyway).

Comment: @Neurax and there we go - edit done